# What's wrong with this ruby program?

Tags: ruby

When I run this code:

```
puts "Welcome to Roglemorph's Addition Calculator"
puts " "
puts " "
puts "What is your first number?"
number1 = gets.chomp * 1
puts "What is your second number?"
number2 = gets.chomp * 1
anwser = number1 + number2
puts anwser
```

it adds the numbers together incorrectly.

[image]

Comment: In the future, please state *in your question* how specifically the code does not work. Also, we prefer text, in both data and code, and images only when text is not sufficient, so the fact that you can't add images yet is not really that big of a restriction.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your program, except that `* 1` is redundant, and the variable name `anwser` looks stupid.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off-topic because Questions seeking debugging help (“**why isn't this code working?**”) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

You are adding strings.

`gets` is `"1\n"`; `gets.chomp` is `"1"`; multiplied by 1 it is still `"1"` (because `String#*` is replication, not multiplication: `"1" * 3 == "111"`). Then `"1" + "2" == "12"`.

You want `gets.chomp.to_i` instead of `gets.chomp*1`.